# WPF : How to bind textbox with resource in 2 ways?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I would like to bind WPF Textbox with resource (two ways) and I would like access to this variable in my code.

Here is my xaml code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="SearchPattern">Eric</system:String>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBox Name="TxbRecherche" Margin="20,0" Text="{StaticResource SearchPattern }" >
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding BtnRechercher_OnClickechercher_Click}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Here is my c# code :

```
private void BtnRechercher_OnClickechercher_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchPattern = this.Resources["SearchPattern"].ToString();
        TbxStatus.Text = " Recherche de '" + searchPattern + "' en cours ...";

        //Lancement de la fenêtre de chargement dans un autre thread..
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            pbRechercheEnCours.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            lblRechercheEnCours.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(searchPattern);
        }
    }
```

What is missing ?

Comment: I also tried <TextBox Name="TxbRecherche" Margin="20,0" Text="{Binding Path=SearchPattern, Mode=TwoWay}" > but now my textbox doesn't bind with this  resource ...

Comment: tbh your question is not clear, what is the expectation ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextBox` is not bound to any `DataContext` (instead it is bound to a `StaticResource`).
You should bind to a property of a self defined class used as `DataContext`. You can set the `DataContext` in the code behind.

Init of window:

```
this.DataContext = new MyModel();
```

Anwhere in your code behind:

```
MessageBox.Show(DataContext.MyPattern);
```

In your Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyPattern}/>
```